# Añadir Objetos a ArrayLIst en otra clase (Java)

Tags: java

Tengo una duda. He creado un programa en Java para añadir objetos a un Array List que debe estar en otra clase.

Anteriormente he hecho esto teniendo todo el código en la misma clase, y ahí no tengo problemas pero a la hora de crear objetos y conectar con la clase que tiene el ArrayList y añadirlos es cuando tengo problemas.

/ARRAY LIST DUDAS CUANDO ESTÁ EN OTRA CLASE

```
package arraylisttest;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import utilidades.AlumnoTest;
import utilidades.ListaDeAlumnosTest;

public class ArrayListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //llamo al metodo menú
       Menu();
    }

    private static void Menu() {
        //Creo un menu para elegir entre añadir alumnos con nombre
        //y apellido y ver un listado de alumnos

        //1. No estoy seguro si la siguiente linea está bien en este lugar....
        ListaDeAlumnosTest lista = new ListaDeAlumnosTest();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opcion;
        boolean check = true;
        boolean check2 = true;
        String nombre, apellido2;


        //BUCLE PARA MENU de 2 OPCIONES
        do{

        while(check){
        System.out.println("Elije 1 para añadir 2 para mostrar todos: ");
        opcion = input.nextInt();


        switch(opcion){
            case 1:
            System.out.println("Añadir alumno.");
            AlumnoTest alumno = introducirAlumnos(lista); //Dudo si es así..    
            break;

            case 2:
            System.out.println("Ver listado de alumnos");
            ListaDeAlumnosTest.listadoPersonas((List) lista); //Netbeans me
            //obliga a ponerlo asi
            break;

            default:
                check = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        }while (check2);
    } //menu

    private static AlumnoTest introducirAlumnos(ListaDeAlumnosTest lista) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        AlumnoTest alumno = null; //Si no hago esto me da error
        String nombre, apellido1;


        System.out.println("Introduce el nombre: ");
        nombre = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduce el primer apellido:  ");
        apellido1 = input.nextLine(); 


        alumno = new AlumnoTest(nombre, apellido1);
        alumno.setNombre(nombre);
        alumno.setApellido1(apellido1);
```

Hasta aquí no se si está correcto, pero luego cuando quiero añadir los objetos alumnos, no entiendo como debe hacerse. He probado con las dos opciones siguientes pero la primera opción no parece funcionar

```
        lista.addAlum(alumno); //de esta manera no parece funcionar,
        //no entiendo por qué no se llama a la clase
        ListaDeAlumnosTest.addAlum(alumno); //Netbeans no acepta esta. 
        //Me dice non static method cannot be referenced from static context

        return alumno;
    }

}
```

Esta es la clase donde tengo el ArrayList

```
package utilidades;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class ListaDeAlumnosTest {
    public ArrayList<AlumnoTest> lista;
    private static int totalAlum;


    public ListaDeAlumnosTest(){ 
        lista = new ArrayList();
    }

    //METODO PARA AÑADIR ALUMNOS A LA LISTA
    public void addAlum(AlumnoTest alumno) {
        lista.add(alumno);
        totalAlum++;
    }


    public static void mostrarPersona(AlumnoTest alumno) {
        System.out.println("\nNombre->"+ alumno.getNombre());
        System.out.println("Apellido1->"+ alumno.getApellido1());
    }

     /**Metodo para seleccionar objetos de la lista y llamar a un método para imprimir
     * @param lista - Objetos de la lista personas
     */
    public static void listadoPersonas(List lista) {
        for(int i = 0; i< lista.size(); i++){  
          mostrarPersona((AlumnoTest) lista.get(i));
        }
    }
    }
```

Esta es la clase AlumnoTest

```
package utilidades;


public class AlumnoTest {

    private String nombre, apellido1, apellido2;

    public AlumnoTest(){

}
    /**Metodo constructor de la clase alumno. Dudo de si el constructor debe ser así o no debería tener parámetros
     * @param nombre
     * @param apellido1
     * */
    public AlumnoTest(String nombre, String apellido1) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido1 = apellido1;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido1() {
        return apellido1;
    }

    public void setApellido1(String apellido1) {
        this.apellido1 = apellido1;
    }

}
```

Si alguien me pudiera guiar lo agradecería !
Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo siguiente:

Modificamos la clase ListaDeAlumnosTest, quitamos los metodos estaticos y variables estaticas, ya que en teoria deben ser solo accesibles dentro de la clase

```
public class ListaDeAlumnosTest {
    private ArrayList<AlumnoTest> lista;
    private int totalAlum;

    public ListaDeAlumnosTest(){ 
        lista = new ArrayList();
    }

    /**
     *@param alumno 
     */
    public void addAlum(AlumnoTest alumno) {
        lista.add(alumno);
        this.totalAlum++;
    }
     /**
     *Metodo para seleccionar objetos de la lista y llamar a un método para imprimir
     * @param lista - Objetos de la lista personas
     */
    public void listadoPersonas() {
        for(int i = 0; i< lista.size(); i++){  
          mostrarPersona((AlumnoTest) lista.get(i));
        }
    }
    /**
     * @param alumno
     */
    private void mostrarPersona(AlumnoTest alumno) {
        System.out.println("\nNombre->"+ alumno.getNombre());
        System.out.println("Apellido1->"+ alumno.getApellido1());
    }
}
```

El mayor problema viene en el método menú ya que algunas variables no son accesibles dentro de los otros métodos, ya que solo viven al momento de ejecutar el método. Por lo que tienes dos opciones, declararlas globales o inyectarlos. Por facilidad los declaramos global para poder acceder a ellos, quedando de la siguiente manera

```
public static ListaDeAlumnosTest lista = new ListaDeAlumnosTest();
private static void Menu() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int opcion;
    boolean check = true;
    boolean check2 = true;


 //Retiro el check2 ya que nunca cambia de estado, por lo que el programa quedaria ciclado eternamente hasta que pares el proceso
    while(check){
    System.out.println("Elije 1 para añadir 2 para mostrar todos, cualquier otro numero para salir: ");
    opcion = input.nextInt();
    switch(opcion){
        case 1:
        System.out.println("Añadir alumno.");
        introducirAlumno();  
        break;
        case 2:
        System.out.println("Ver listado de alumnos");
//Para listar solo es necesario llamar al metodo de la clase ListaDeAlumnosTest ya que el ArrayList vive dentro de la clase
        lista.listadoPersonas();
        break;
        default:
            check = false;
            break;
        }
    }
} 


private static void introducirAlumno() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    AlumnoTest alumno = new AlumnoTest();
    System.out.println("Introduce el nombre: ");
    nombre = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Introduce el primer apellido:  ");
    apellido1 = input.nextLine(); 
//Quito el constructor, ya que haces el set después, por lo que es repetitivo, puedes quitar el set agregando los valores al constructor o hacer el set.
    alumno.setNombre(nombre);
    alumno.setApellido1(apellido1);
    lista.addAlum(alumno);
}
```

Prácticamente con esto funcionaria, te recomiendo que cheques un poco de cuando y como se pueden acceder a variables en los objetos en Java, diferenciar cuando usar estáticos y cuando no, y sobre todo la programación orientada a objetos, pues el mayor problema viene de entender y llevar a la practica el paradigma

Answer (score 0):

La primera opción me da error también a mi por:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.example.demo.ListaDeAlumnosTest cannot be cast to java.util.List
at com.example.demo.ArrayListTest.Menu(ArrayListTest.java:39)
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
```

Entiendo que quieres pasar al metodo una `ListaDeAlumnosTest` y mostar cada uno del atributo  `public ArrayList<AlumnoTest> lista;` . El método `introducirAlumnos` no seria necesario que devuelva el `AlumnoTest` insertado si no va a hacer nada con el luego, ya que lo añades dentro del método a la lista. Se podria quedar asi:

Cambia el case 1:

```
    case 1:
       System.out.println("Añadir alumno.");
       introducirAlumnos(lista); 
    break;
```

El método se quedaría así:

```
private static void introducirAlumnos(ListaDeAlumnosTest lista) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nombre, apellido1;

    System.out.println("Introduce el nombre: ");
    nombre = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Introduce el primer apellido:  ");
    apellido1 = input.nextLine();

    AlumnoTest alumno = new AlumnoTest(nombre, apellido1);
    lista.addAlum(alumno);
    input.close();
}
```

Si la idea es que la clase ListaDeAlumnosTest tenga un metodo que imprima la info de los alumnos podrias hacerlo asi:

```
 public static ArrayList<AlumnoTest> lista;
 public static void listadoPersonas() {
   for(int i = 0; i< lista.size(); i++){  
     mostrarPersona(lista.get(i));
   }
 }
```

Y el segundo case asi:

```
case 2:
   System.out.println("Ver listado de alumnos");
   ListaDeAlumnosTest.listadoPersonas();
break;
```

Un saludo.